# Dask read_csv throws error 'ZipExtFile' object has no attribute 'startswith' when trying to read a zipped csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a this block of code that is trying to read a zipped csv file using Dask.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
with fs.open('/filename.csv.zip') as f:
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(f) 
    file = zf.open('filename.csv', 'r')
    df = dd.read_csv(file)
```

When running this block of code, I get an AttributeError: 'ZipExtFile' object has no attribute 'startswith', but if I convert the last line to just use pandas to read the csv file, the dataframe is read as expected. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dask prefers not to work on file-like objects directly, because it needs to care about potentially serialising all arguments and sending them to workers elsewhere. However, fsspec handles complex paths for you, so you can achieve what you want more simply:

```
df = dd.read_csv("zip://filename.csv::file://filename.csv.zip")
```

(you can omit "file://" as it is the default backend, but I include it to be explicit)

For reference, the docstring says that the argument must be string(s):

> urlpath : string or list
> Absolute or relative filepath(s). Prefix with a protocol like `s3://`
> to read from alternative filesystems. To read from multiple files you
> can pass a globstring or a list of paths, with the caveat that they
> must all have the same protocol.

Comment: Wow, didn't realize `fsspec` could do this!

Comment: This is a helpful answer but does not completely solve my issue since the zip file I am attempting to access is received from an sftp connection made using fssec. The connection requires a private key which I don't think the dd.read_csv file call allows. Do you know any solutions?

Comment: If fsspec opened it, you can! You would need to add "::ssh://user:pw@host:port/path", and you can add extra arguments to the SSH backend `storage_options={"ssh": {...}}`.

Comment: I am still struggling with trying what you are saying. I tried to call dd.read_csv('::ssh://user:@host:port/zip://filename.csv::file://filename.csv.zip". storage_options = {'ssh':{'key_filename':'./key_file'}}) and this just gives me a the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect error, pointing to a local directory.

Comment: Now I tried it again wtih this as the url: ''zip://::ssh://user:@host:port/filename.csv.zip" and the connection is made but I am getting a file not found error.

Comment: I am at a loss. When I try to read a csv using zip://::ssh://user:@host:port/*.csv.zip as the url, the connection works as I receive an error that this path does not resolve to exactly one fie. However when I specify the file name, I get a file not found error. Additionally when I try to remove the zip:// beginning string the url starts to point to my local directories. I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: "zip://filename.csv::ssh://user:pw@host:port/myfile.csv.zip". There must be just one zip file, but it can contain multiple CSVs.